# Sublime Linter not highlighting

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

Sublime Linter suddenly isn't displaying the nice ui highlighting it used to. It also isn't displaying lint messages in the bottom left of sublime. This may have happened after a recent windows update, but i wasn't paying close enough attention to be sure exactly when it occurred. I've followed the troubleshooting section on the documentation, and verified jshint is working in the command line. I've also switched to debug mode but I see no Linter errors in the console. I've also tried switching to manual lint mode, but the "Lint This View" option is grayed out. Not sure what to do at this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you recently updated your copy of Windows, so it's possible that the Environment Variable for node(and other variables) have been removed or erased, I suggest you check that first.